# Receive Event in BackgoundTask and react in UI

Tags: c#, background-task, windows-10-mobile

I use this Code Example:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sms-SendReceive-fa02e55e
to read incoming SMS on a w10m-device.

I need to catch 1 special SMS with some trigger and show it on the screen.

Can I open the App if the special trigger was inside the SMS?

Or is it possible to use the BackgroundTask inside of the same class and so being able to access the ui?

Or is it possible to use this as an async Task?

Comment: Or can I do something in C#.  What do want to do and what have you tried?

Comment: I want to read an SMS while the app is open. So basically I'd like to skip the whole Background-Stuff and just wait async until my message arrives. All I tried so far was: I have successfully built the win10-universal-"SmsSendAndReceive"-example. Also I started a new project where I can send SMS silently. But now I need to receive the answer and the only way to do so is in the BackgroundTask, afaik. And I need to get into the app from the BackgroundTask or read the SMS inside the active app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is: I use the BackgroundTask and store the received message as an XML-file. After the BackgroundTask closes it fires an event inside my app where I check whether such a file exists or not. If it does, I can read it and have all my stuff, can display it and can go on with my work :)